# gmdate() in function parameter gives parse error

Tags: php

I'm using PHP 5.3.5 with Fast-CGI.

When I try to use `gmdate()` to set the initial value for a parameter, I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in
>   MyClass.php on line 3

Here's my code (line 3 is the line where myFunction is declared):

```
function myFunction($myDate = gmdate('Y-m-d')) {
    // ...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? This also occurs if I do the same thing in a class function.

Comment: +1/2 for interesting question and another +1/2 for being a female non-nerd coder ;)

Comment: Thanks, I wrap all of my half points up in pink lace and rainbows. :)

Comment: You guys are missing the point, this is serious business ([nyan nyan nyan](http://nyan.cat/)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a function as a default value for a function or method parameter.

```
function myFunction($myDate = '') {
    $myDate = (!empty($myDate)) ? $myDate :  gmdate('Y-m-d');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: can I leave the `= ''` part off and do `!isset($myDate)` instead?

Comment: No, because if the parameter is not included in the function call an error will be thrown.

Comment: Leaving `= ''` off implies the param is required and php will throw warnings if you don't pass in an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Including a validation:

```
function myFunction($myDate = '')
{
    $myDate = preg_match('/\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/', $myDate) ? $myDate : gmdate('Y-m-d');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @ami Did you tested this solution?